# Minimax algorithim tic tac toe not working

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

My code for the minimax algorithm tic tac toe AI seems to be not working, and I cannot figure out why. It seems to be something wrong with the recusrion aspect and returning a negative value if a move results in a loss; it doesn't differentiate between a defensive move vs. an offensive move.

Instead of choosing to place X on position 6 to stop the opponent from reaching 3 in a row, it instead places it on another tile

```
board = [
        "X", "X", "O",
        "O", "O", "X",
        "-", "-", "-",
        ]

opp = "O"
plyr = "X"

def getOpenPos(board):
    openPos = []
    for index, state in enumerate(board):
        if state == "-":
            openPos.append(index)
    return openPos

def winning(board, plyr):
    if ((board[0] == plyr and board[1] == plyr and board[2] == plyr) or 
        (board[3] == plyr and board[4] == plyr and board[5] == plyr) or 
        (board[6] == plyr and board[7] == plyr and board[8] == plyr) or
        (board[0] == plyr and board[4] == plyr and board[8] == plyr) or
        (board[1] == plyr and board[4] == plyr and board[7] == plyr) or
        (board[2] == plyr and board[4] == plyr and board[6] == plyr) or
        (board[0] == plyr and board[3] == plyr and board[6] == plyr) or
        (board[2] == plyr and board[5] == plyr and board[8] == plyr)):
        return True
    else:
        return False 

def minimax(board, turn, FIRST):
    possibleMoves = getOpenPos(board)
    #check if won
    if (winning(board, opp)):
        return -10
    elif (winning(board, plyr)):
        return 10

    scores = []

    #new board created for recursion, and whoevers turn it is
    for move in possibleMoves:
        newBoard = board
        newBoard[move] = turn


        if (turn == plyr):
            scores.append( [move,minimax(newBoard, opp, False)] )
        elif (turn == opp):
            scores.append( [move, minimax(newBoard, plyr, False)] )

    #collapse recursion by merging all scores to find optimal position
    #see if there is a negative value (loss) and if there is its a -10
    if not FIRST:
        bestScore = 0
        for possibleScore in scores:
            move = possibleScore[0]
            score = possibleScore[1]
            if score == -10:
                return -10
            else:
                if score > bestScore:
                    bestScore = score
        return bestScore

    else:
        bestMove, bestScore = 0, 0
        for possibleScore in scores:
            move = possibleScore[0]
            score = possibleScore[1]
            if score > bestScore:
                bestMove = move
                bestScore = score

        #returns best position
        return bestMove



print(minimax(board, plyr, True))
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues with your code.  If you fix them, you at least will get `6` as a result in this case.

First issue is that the line `newBoard = board` is not actually making a copy of the list, it is just making a copy of the reference.  That can be fixed by changing it to `newBoard = board[:]`.

Second issue is that your starting value for `bestScore` is not actually out of the expected range, so you don't get a value for `bestIndex` every time.  I changed `bestMove, bestScore = 0, 0` to `bestMove, bestScore = 0, -11` and it seemed to work for me.